# graphical methods / deep architectures for collaborative filtering

Tags: graphical-model, recommender-system, deep-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

Having read "[Restricted Boltzmann Machines for Collaborative Filtering" (Salakhutdinov et. al. 2007)](http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2007/papers/407.pdf), I'm wondering if there has been any follow-up work on applying graphical and/or deep architectures for recommendation engines.

The paper suggests some interesting possible extensions, such as using stacked RBMs instead of single-layer ones. However, I didn't find any follow-up papers by Salakhutdinov's publication page.

Answer (score 1):

There are some publications using auto encoders instead of RBMs. This article is really interesting: https://www.nicta.com.au/pub-download/full/8604/

There is also works on content-based recommendation using deep learning techniques such as this from spotify: http://benanne.github.io/2014/08/05/spotify-cnns.html

Another very recent (2016) publication is "Deep Neural Networks for YouTube Recommendations" https://research.google.com/pubs/pub45530.html - It feeds a deep network with user activies and video embeddings and dense features as well

Those works could lead you to great references also.